# Trying to install sonarqube on linux machine but getting error

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am trying to install sonarqube-5.1 on Linux x86_64 and I did below steps

**1:** sudo wget http://downloads.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.zip

**2:** unzip sonarqube-5.1.zip

**3:** sudo mv sonarqube-5.1 /usr/local/

**4:** sudo /usr/local/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start

**output**
Starting SonarQube...

Started SonarQube.

But when I am trying to open http://my_local_IP:9000 Then It is giving below error

**Unable to connect**

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at my_local_IP:9000.

1. The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in
   a few moments.
2. If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
3. If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Had I missed anything in above steps, please help with correct/missed steps.

Below is the sonar.log

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2015.09.29 05:58:22 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-28.b13.el6_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/cadmin/software/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process7829107144547289706properties
2015.09.29 05:58:22 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.09.29 05:58:22 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-28.b13.el6_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/cadmin/software/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process7829107144547289706properties
2015.09.29 05:58:22 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.09.29 05:58:22 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2015.09.29 05:58:23 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443520701614] version[1.4.4], pid[31840], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
2015.09.29 05:58:23 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443520701614] initializing ...
2015.09.29 05:58:23 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1443520701614] loaded [], sites []
2015.09.29 05:58:26 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443520701614] initialized
2015.09.29 05:58:26 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443520701614] starting ...
2015.09.29 05:58:26 WARN   es[o.e.common.network]  failed to resolve local host, fallback to loopback
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-my_private_IP.ec2.internal: ip-my_private_IP.ec2.internal: unknown error
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1484) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkUtils.<clinit>(NetworkUtils.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.createClientBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:350) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:250) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:91) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.start(InternalNode.java:242) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.start(SearchServer.java:46) [sonar-search-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) [sonar-process-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.start(SearchServer.java:46) [sonar-search-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) [sonar-process-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.main(SearchServer.java:80) [sonar-search-5.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-my_private_IP.ec2.internal: unknown error
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1479) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
2015.09.29 05:58:26 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1443520701614] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/my_private_IP:9001]}
2015.09.29 05:58:26 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1443520701614] sonarqube/LmpMNIoNRo6GxkSamD74sQ
2015.09.29 05:58:29 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1443520701614] new_master [sonar-1443520701614][LmpMNIoNRo6GxkSamD74sQ][localhost][inet[/my_private_IP:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1443520701614}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2015.09.29 05:58:29 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443520701614] started
2015.09.29 05:58:29 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1443520701614] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2015.09.29 05:58:29 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2015.09.29 05:58:30 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-28.b13.el6_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/cadmin/software/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/home/cadmin/software/sonarqube-5.1/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process1305181292822442579properties
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
2015.09.29 05:58:31 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2015.09.29 05:58:31 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: /home/cadmin/software/sonarqube-5.1/web
2015.09.29 05:58:31 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2015.09.29 05:58:31 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: /home/cadmin/software/sonarqube-5.1/web
2015.09.29 05:58:32 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-my_public_IP-38099"]
2015.09.29 05:58:32 ERROR web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-my_public_IP-38099"]
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:340) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:340) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:40) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) [sonar-process-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:66) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
2015.09.29 05:58:32 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardService] Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-38099]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-38099]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:340) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:40) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) [sonar-process-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:66) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
2015.09.29 05:58:32 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:65) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:40) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) ~[sonar-process-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:66) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-38099]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:574) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
2015.09.29 05:58:32 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
2015.09.29 05:58:32 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2015.09.29 05:58:32 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443520701614] stopping ...
2015.09.29 05:58:32 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443520701614] stopped
2015.09.29 05:58:32 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443520701614] closing ...
2015.09.29 05:58:32 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443520701614] closed
2015.09.29 05:58:32 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: You can refer sonar.log and access.log under log folder in sonarQube

Comment: Thanks Reena, I have checked logs, I think it seems to be a firewall issue. because I can see "failed to resolve local host, fallback to loopback". please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Please prefix code with 4 spaces, and don't put them in a code snippet block because it generates a "Run code snippet" button (which is useless in this case)

Comment: Have you got enabled selinux? If yes, then disable it temporary `setenforce 0`. If it will work, then you need to decide "enable it and configure" or "leave it as it is".

Answer (score 1):

We had this same issue and were able to resolve it by adding the hostname into /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

`"java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address"`

it is mostly due to port conflicts. some other services on host might have used port 9000.
change the default sonar port from 9000 to 9080 or any random port which is open.

`sonar.web.port=9080`  in sonar.properties file 
and restart the sonar service.

to check logs on continuous basis , run

`tailf <sonarqube-installation-directory>/logs/sonar.log`  command.

To check whether 9000 port is occupied by any process or not,
stop sonar service, kill sonar process if it is present and fire following command:

`netstat -anp | grep 9000`